# Parse error of nested tuples in scala

Tags: syntax, scala, tuples

When writing the following code in scala

```
var m = Map((0,1) -> "a")
m += ((0,2), "b") // compilation error
```

I'm getting the error

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: (Int, Int)
```

However the changing the syntax of the tuple from `(X,Y)` to `(X -> Y)` works

```
var m = Map((0,1) -> 'a)
m += ((0,2) -> 'b) // compiles file
```

Even though

```
((0,1).getClass == (0 -> 1).getClass) // is true
(0,1).isInstanceOf[Tuple2[_,_]] && (0 -> 1).isInstanceOf[Tuple2[_,_]] // both true
```

Why is that? What does scala think my nested tuple is?

Comment: I *always* make the same mistake

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is pretty simple (I think) and has to do with the fact that (on the `Map` trait):

```
m += (a -> b)
```

is shorthand for:

```
m = m.+(t2) //where t2 is of type Tuple2[A,B]
```

Obviously if you use a comma in the first example, Scala will interpret this as being a call to the method:

```
m = m.+(a, b)
```

**This method does not exist** on the `Map` trait. Method invocation rules mean that **`a -> b`** gets evaluated first (to the `Tuple2`) and hence the correct method is called. **Note:** Using an extra pair of parentheses works just fine:

```
m += ( (a,b) ) //works just fine but less readable
```

Comment: I was actually pretty sure that Obj Op Pred is equivalent to Pred.Op((Pred)) already. Is there a use (in the standard library, or Lift) for calling a function with two arguments as an operator? (An example which makes sense of course, you can always do "array update (x,y)" but it just looks strange.

Comment: I agree with you Elazar. I think that the compiler should have a bit more sense here

Answer (score 0):

Oxbow is correct. You can use another parenthesis to disambiguate, though:

```
m += (((0,2), "b"))
```

Comment: I believe I pointed out that the extra parentheses solved the issue